How to play alarm sound from push in react native firebase android device also when device is on mute (DND) like critical alert in iOS
In iOS there is option for send critical push.
{
  "apns": {
    "headers": {
      "apns-priority": "10",
      "apns-push-type": "alert"
    },
    "payload": {
      "aps": {
        "alert": {
          "title": "xxxx",
          "body": "yyyyy"
        },
        "sound": {
          "critical": 1,
          "name": "alarm.mp3",
          "volume": 1.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

In the sound dictionary you can pass critical, sound name and volume.
How can I make the same logic on android devices? I didn't found the official Documentation about it.
I am looking for the server json struct . and also what to do in the app side will be great (less important for now but can also be great ).
Thanks for your help!
I trying to play alarm sound on android device also when the phone is on mute, using firebase react native.
Thanks for your help!

How did you make the alarm sound play for critical alert in ios? Can you provide me some reference. I'm not able to play the sound in ios.

@charlie2, you can look at guide,I hope its will help you.
